# Email authentication without modifying DNS records

Tags: spf, dkim

Can someone explain how Mailchimp does email authentication without user having to update SPF or DKIM records?

Quote from Mailchimp:

> When you use MailChimp's authentication, campaigns will pass SenderID, SPF, DomainKeys, and DKIM checks. Since it's turned on by default you don't need to do anything extra in order to enable the authentication of your emails.

But I couldn't find any technical information on how that works.

Answer (score 3):

As I see on some email I recieved from a mailchimp campaign, emails are being sent from mailchimp's own domain, so sender comes from, for example, mail28.wdc03.rsgsv.net, that's its own domain, so obviously they do have all setup correctly and you are seeing the from: and reply-to: header on your email coming from your original email address.

Comment: So `from` and `reply-to` shows info@company.com. But how does receiving mail server and spam filters know that *.rsgsv.net is authorized to send emails for company.com?

Comment: from and reply-to are headers that can be written to whatever you want in the data part of an email and usually is what email clients show as from, what's the actual sender address comes in the 'mail' [smtp protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview) command and that's where mailchimp's own address is used and thus authenticates correctly as their domain is already setup.

Comment: So is the the only way you'd be able to do this is to self-host your mail servers behind domains you control and can thus validate SPF/DKIM against those?